# error parallax effect in firefox but works on google chrome

Tags: firefox, parallax

I need your help my website is not functioning properly on firefox browser but in edge, chrome and opera and safari it works only firefox is not functioning properly

[Firefox Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcZG8.png)

[Google Chrome Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acath.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting up all your projects in Xampp or something similar first before testing it. If you are going to upload to a server you need to replicate the environment locally before you decide whether it is going to work or not. It seems complicated but it is quite simple, you can find out more here. https://www.apachefriends.org/

That said, check your urls, they are not the same for your two different screens, the one is referencing an anchor tag.

Comment: I already test it using a true domain and host and I already test it using xampp but same problem facing.

Comment: Check this out in Firefox and Chrome you can see the problem as the screenshot shown. http://test.cambridgeschoolinc.org/